# Is there a way to disable / disallow someone from using View Creator using Diagram Tool in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

We have a lot of DB and BI analysts who regularly create views. Some folks create these views using SSMS' view creator which allows someone to drag and drop tables. This creates a lot of problems when we need to review or modify their code as the diagram tool in SSMS messes up the indentations and formatting, making it impossible to review the code. Is there an option or permission that I can revoke/change that disallows everyone from using it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The view designer comes with SSMS and cannot be managed by any database engine. So, you can completely block them from creating views with DENY permission (as long as they are not `sysadmin` role members), but you **cannot** restrict them using SSMS features as the features installed in their local PC:

```
DENY create view to ApplicationUser
```

Comment: they obviously need to continue creating views. So this is not a solution to this issue by any means. However, in retrospect, when I think about your rationale (SSMS is a client feature as opposed to a permission), I completely understand and agree that it's probably not possible to disable it.